# Can not connect sqlite3 with c using mingw on windows

Tags: c++, c, sqlite, mingw

I want to use sqlite3 as a database interface for my c++, so i decided to start from this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm

I have installed sqlite3 on my computer and add a environment variable for it, but when I try to compile a very simple program as the tutorial suggest by typing

```
gcc test.c -l sqlite3
```

on command prompt, I get the following error:

```
   test.c:2:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <sqlite3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

The test.c file is a folder on my desktop. The folder has the following structure:

```
test.c
shell.c
sqlite3.c
sqlite3.h
sqlite3ext.h
```

The last four files are from the amalgamation zip I found on the https://www.sqlite.org/download.html (sqlite-amalgamation-3320300.zip)

I have been looking on what is wrong for hours, and the only possible explanation i can find is that the compiler cant link the external sqlite3 library, but even then I could not find a linking method that works, any ideas on how I can compile the above?

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Edit:

if I type #include "sqlite3.h" instead of #include <sqlite3.h> I get a different error:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Your compiler is telling you it cannot find sqlite3.h. Where on your system is it? Add the -I flag to point your compiler to it.

Comment: @Botje It is in the same directory as the test.c. Something important I forgot to mention is that if I type #include "sqlite3.h"  instead of #include <sqlite3.h> I get a different error: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The new error is you forgot to link to a sqlite library or use the `.c` Amalgamation file in your project. [https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html)

Comment: Your error is now a linker error, not a compiler error.  It looks like you're not familiar with the build process of a C++ (or C) application, compilation and linking.

Comment: Do you have a `libsqlite3.a` file somewhere? Use `-Lyour/path/here` to point the linker to the directory where you have it.

Comment: @drescherjm I have the .c Amalgamation file, I updated my post so you can see all of my files in the directory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No I do not have libsqlite3.a somewhere, you know how can I get it and I should place it?

Comment: Just having files in a folder will not help you if you don''t use them. The bug is here: `gcc test.c -l sqlite3` You need `gcc test.c sqlite3.c`

Comment: @Ph. You'll probably have to compile it yourself. But if drescherjm's suggestion works, and doesn't cause obscenely long build times, you can stick to it instead.

Comment: @drescherjm That was going to be be my suggestion as well. I was able to reproduce the problem and I got it working with the same command.

Comment: I successfully compiled the program using `gcc test.c sqlite3.c` (for those wondering, the compilation took some time)  thank all of you. I could not imagine that it would something that easy, because I needed to install sqlite and I imagined that the compilation of the source files was not needed. I will check why the guide suggested the installation of sqlite and I will update the post. I really appreciate the help I got here, wish everyone the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
gcc test.c -l sqlite3
```

you are attempting to link to a `libsqlite3.a` file which you don't have.

From the comments you do have the Amalgamation file `sqlite.c`. The documentation for this is here: https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html

One simple way to use this is you can just build it with your executable like this:

```
gcc test.c sqlite3.c -o myexecutable
```

Comment: I tried something similar for linux: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc pflanzen.cpp sqlite3.c -o herbarium.exe
on linux, but it did not work. I am unsure whether this is a similar problem or not.
The file is called sqlite3.c here.